# Bash script to delete aws s3 delete markers that have spaces in the key name

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have found the following bash script online that will iterate over an s3 bucket and delete the object with delete markers:

```
$ sh delete_deletemarker.sh “my-bucket-name” “/path/to/a/directory”

#!/bin/bash
BUCKET=$1
PREFIX=$2
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $BUCKET --prefix $PREFIX --output text | 
 grep "DELETEMARKERS" | while read OBJECTS
   do
        KEY=$( echo $OBJECTS| awk '{print $3}')
        VERSION_ID=$( echo $OBJECTS | awk '{print $5}')
        echo $KEY
        echo $VERSION_ID
        aws s3api delete-object --bucket $BUCKET --key $KEY --version-id $VERSION_ID
    done
```

The only issue with this script, is that if the key ('filename') has a space or multiple spaces in the filename, the script will fail. For example a key with *'/cat/is_my_cat.jpg'* will work, but *'/cat/is my cat.jpg'* will not work. How would I change the above script to facilitate both keyname instances?

Comment: Quote it! `$KEY` should be `"$KEY"` everywhere and all the variables prefixed with `$`

Comment: offtopic: And change variable names to lowercase. Avoid confusion with bash variables.

Comment: @Inian setting both variables to use quotes as you suggested is not solving my problem. The `$VERSION_ID` becomes cut off :(

Comment: Have you tried `aws s3api delete-object --bucket "$BUCKET" --key "$KEY" --version-id "$VERSION_ID"`? Worst case, you could rewrite it as a Python script. Are you basically trying to fully-delete any object that has been soft-deleted?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I would like to keep it as a bash script. I am trying to iterate over a bucket and remove the objects with delete markers - so that all objects are not deleted. The above script works great, but when the keyname has spaces the above script fails - and here I am...

Comment: What about situations where an object has been deleted and subsequently re-uploaded? This would put the delete marker as somewhere in the middle of the versions (not at the top). Would you still want to delete that whole object, or just the versions prior to the delete marker?